# How to write a paragraph describing motion?

Tags: science

I'm doing a lab report for a general physics course, and for a written portion I have to describe the motion of an object given by a position vs time graph. How do I stretch this into a 1/2-page single-spaced paragraph?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Requests to rephrase a single sentence or paragraph are off-topic for us, but may be acceptable on English SE. I've asked the mods if this can be migrated.

Comment: What you have written suggests you don't understand the science rather than it being a writing question. Why is the graph the shape it is? What factors affect the slope? Etc.

Comment: Agreed, this question is asking what to write, which is off-topic here. Closing.

Answer (score 1):

Since the graph shows each distinct position along a time line, you can focus your written description on the trends exposed by the graph.

As the graph above clearly reveals, the position of the widget rose sharply over the first half of the procedure, then leveled off for most of the remaining time.  There are two distinct exceptions to this general trend.  At 4:32, the widget reversed its sharp incline for 15 seconds and at 4:45, it plummeted for 10 seconds following nearly 4 minutes of stability.

From there, you can explore the causes of the unexpected values and the causes of the originally identified general trend.